# Выбрать данные процедурой

Tags: sql-server

```
create table PrivateMessage
 (
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SenderAccountId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
AcceptorAccountId int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);create table Account
(
 Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Nick NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT N'Пользователь'
 );
```

Имеются 2 таблицы. В таблице Account представлены Id аккаунта, которые могут присутствовать в SenderAccountId или AcceptorAccountId, и ник пользователя с таким Id. В таблице PrivateMessage представлены Id сообщения, Id аккаунта автора сообщения - SenderAccountId - и Id аккаунта получателя сообщения - AcceptorAccountId. На вход процедуры поступает Id аккаунта пользователя, для которого нужно получить Id аккаунтов и Nick пользователей, которые хотя бы раз писали сообщение этому пользователю или получали сообщение от него. Моя попытка:

```
SELECT Id,Nick from Account where Id 
in((select SenderAccountId from PrivateMessage
 WHERE SenderAccountId=@AccountId)union
 (select AcceptorAccountId from PrivateMessage
  where AcceptorAccountId=@AccountId))
 intersect select Id from Account where Id=@AccountId;
```

Вот моя вторая попытка, но я не уверен в его правильности:

```
select distinct Account.Id,Nick from Account 
inner join PrivateMessage on SenderAccountId!=AcceptorAccountId
where (Account.Id!=@AccountId)and(SenderAccountId=@AccountId or     AcceptorAccountId=@AccountId);
```

Подскажите, правильно ли выводит этот запрос?

P.S. В итоге получилась такая процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPrivateMessagesAuthors(@AccountId int=1)
      AS 
      BEGIN 
(select distinct Account.Id,Nick from Account 
inner join PrivateMessage on Account.Id=SenderAccountId
where AcceptorAccountId=@AccountId)union
(select distinct Account.Id,Nick from Account 
inner join PrivateMessage on Account.Id=AcceptorAccountId
where SenderAccountId=@AccountId);  
      end
```

Можно ли написать ещё более оптимальный запрос?

Comment: @Alex9, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Проблема в том, чтобы выбрать всех собеседников пользователя по известному его Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика запроса написана правильно, должен работать корректно.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Account.Id, Nick
FROM Account
INNER JOIN PrivateMessage
    ON SenderAccountId != AcceptorAccountId
WHERE (Account.Id != @AccountId)
    AND (
        SenderAccountId = @AccountId
        OR AcceptorAccountId = @AccountId
        );
```

По поводу процедуры - она тоже написана логически верно.

Но её можно ещё и ускорить:
 1. Используя UNION ALL вместо просто UNION.
 2. Обернув ваши запросы в более один общий запрос, вынеся DISTINCT в него, а в мелких вообще убрать этот дистинкт.

Поясню разницу: UNION выполняет выборку, а делает над ней DISTINCT, то есть убирает все дубликаты. В отличие от него, UNION ALL просто сделает выборку, но с дубликатами. На больших массивах данных эффект будет ощутимый, если использовать UNION ALL.
Скорость работы DISTINCT оставляет желать лучшего, когда вы делаете его несколько раз за один запрос. Проще получить все данные и над общей выборкой сделать дистинкт.

Вот что получается:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPrivateMessagesAuthors (@AccountId INT = 1)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Nick
    FROM
    ( 
        (
            SELECT Account.Id, Nick
            FROM Account
            INNER JOIN PrivateMessage
                ON Account.Id = SenderAccountId
            WHERE AcceptorAccountId = @AccountId
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT Account.Id, Nick
            FROM Account
            INNER JOIN PrivateMessage
                ON Account.Id = AcceptorAccountId
            WHERE SenderAccountId = @AccountId
        )
    ) a
END
```

Comment: Неверный синтаксис возле ;

Comment: Где? В первом запросе?